# How to inflate core/res/res/layout/simple_dropdown_item_2line.xml

Tags: android

There is this xml file under frameworks/base.

/frameworks/base/core/res/res/layout/simple_dropdown_item_2line.xml

How can I inflate that in my own android application?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

`View view = activity.getLayoutInflater().inflate(
     android.R.layout.layout.simple_dropdown_item_2line, null);`

If you are doing this inside Activity code you can use `this` instead of `activity` which implies that you set the variable somewhere

Answer (score 0):

you'd use android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_2line, I believe.